# How to collect files according to their parent directory name

Tags: java, android, file

I have many files which are come from different folders and I want to collect all those files according to their parent folder like

---

- Downloads(20)
- Videos(10)
- Whatsapp(30)

---

I know how to get the parent directory name of the file

```
[file.getParentFile().getName()]
```

but the task for me is how to collect the same name files in one folder icon...

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you please be more specific since i didn't get what really are you looking for,
I mean from what i understand i guess you need to implement a map that contains the parent folders as key's and the children folders as value.

Comment: You will just create a map with folder name of the parent of a file as key and put value as 1 when the key was not already there and on next iterations keep incrementing the value if same key found.

Comment: Or you can also just build a list of file names instead of count. And show the count using list.size

Comment: yes you both are right but i don't only want to show the counts but also when user click on folder name so all the files which are on this folder will show to the users